# How to show a legend as if it was a plot in a matrix of plots (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I have three plots to show and I'd like to place them in a matrix of plots. The first in the top-left corner, the second in the top-right one and the third in the bottom-left one.
These plots share the same legend and I'd like to show it in the bottom-right corner as in the figure:
[image]

I'm using the `ggarrange()` function of the `egg` package to display the plots like this.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe package `patchwork` could help: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html - see last example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to switch to the `patchwork` package:

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_boxplot()


list(p, p, p) |>
  wrap_plots(nrow = 2) +
  guide_area() +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted!